# Creating Multiple Dictionaries from one input file - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an output file that consists of this data.

```
{'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'city': 'Lake Saint Louis'}, {'hash': 415446807, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'},  {'hash': 607324474, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'}
```

Which i've split by using

```
textToSearch = (", {'hash")
textToReplace = ("\n {'hash")

fileToSearch = ("filename.txt")
tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
    tempFile.close()
#Not the simplest script but it works.
```

and i recieve this, appending the original file:

```
{'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'city': 'Lake Saint Louis'}
{'hash': 415446807, 'org': 'CompanyName', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation'}
{'hash': 607324474, 'isp': 'ISP-Name', 'transport': 'tcp', 'data': 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server'}
```

Now i'm trying to get my script to read through the appended file, to treat each line/ set of {} as a new dictionary.

```
file = open ("filename.txt" , "r")
for line in file :
    thisdict =line
    selection = thisdict["postal_code"]
    print (selection)
```

and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\XXXX\XXXX\Documents\XXDocuments\XXXX\FileExtractor.py", line 16, in <module>
print(thisdict[x])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I think its to do with the dictionary iterating over the file and re-writing each dictionary or treating all 3 lines as one big dictionary.

How can I go about either:

1. Setting Each Dict a dynamic name such as Dict(x) where x is +1 each time
2. Split the file into different dictionaries before the *for* loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i believe the reason it's doing this is because when you read from a file you're actually reading in strings, so what you're actually reading are strings that have the following format:
"{'region_code': 'MO', 'postal_code': None, 'country_code': 'US', 'city': 'Lake Saint Louis'}"

try using the json module
although for this to work the qutes in the appending file have to be double quotes, and also take care of the wide open None values by changing them to "null"

```
import json
file = open ("filename.txt" , "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    line = line.replace("\'", '\"')
    line = line.replace("None", 'null')
    thisdict = json.loads(line)  # since its a string
    selection = thisdict["postal_code"]
    print (selection)
    # if you want to read straight from a file you use json.load() instead
```

Comment: [line = line.replace("\'", '\"')] |
Is this to denote replacing the Newlines or to replace the single quotes?

Comment: its to denote replacing single quotes with double quotes as is required with the json module, without this you get an error that tell you to do so

Answer (score 1):

First off,

1. Convert `None` to `null` in json
2. Convert single quotes to double quotes
3. Add `[` in the beginning and ']` at the end of the file

Now load the json using the `json` module. You can easily loop through the dictionaries.

After doing steps 1,2,3,

```
[{"region_code": "MO", "postal_code": null, "country_code": "US", "city": "Lake Saint Louis"}, {"hash": 415446807, "org": "CompanyName", "transport": "tcp", "data": "HTTP/1.0 302 Found\r\nLocation"},  {"hash": 607324474, "isp": "ISP-Name", "transport": "tcp", "data": "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server"}]
```

Now you can easily load the json file.

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

for ind_dict in data:
    print(ind_dict)
```

Comment: precisely, although you do not actually have to add the "[" "]"

Comment: It won't work without the square brackets @TochiBedford

Comment: oh i guess it's cause i did it differently in my answer above